# Cannot access child value on JValue in Azure Mobile App

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I recently implemented custom authentication with Azure Mobile App - All the server side works fine and also my web application which is using that mobile app service is working fine. I tested the server-side in details with POSTMAN and with different scenarios, everything works fine until I try to `LoginAsync` on Xamarin.

When I pass email and password in POSTMAN, I get the following response as a clear indication that it is working

[image]

but when I send a request from my app using `LoginAsync` I get the following error.

> **Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue**

My code to send request is fairly simple as following

```
public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
 {
   string username = "todo@gmail.com";
   string password = "todo";
   string message = string.Empty;
   var success = false;
   var credentials = new JObject
      {
       ["email"] = username,
       ["password"] = password
       };
   try
     {              
      MobileServiceUser user = await client.LoginAsync("CustomAuth", credentials);
      if (user != null)
        {
          success = true;
          CreateAndShowDialog("OK", "Auth");                 
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
         {
           CreateAndShowDialog(ex, "Auth Error");                
          }

  return success;
 }
```

where I am calling it as follows

```
private MobileServiceClient client;
client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL);
await Authenticate();
```

Any idea why I am getting `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` error?

Cheers

**EDIT POST**

As a workaround, I am temporarily using `InvokeApiAsync` with `JObject.FromObject` instead of `LoginAsync`

`await client.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/login/CustomAuth", JObject.FromObject(credentials), HttpMethod.Post, null);`

I am still not sure why `LoginAsync` does not work - Until I find a solution I will keep using `InvokdeApiAsync` as a workaround

Comment: Not familiar with the syntax of JObject you have mentioned. Can you try with `var credentials = new JObject(new
      {
       email = username,
       password = password
       });`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, now i got this error after i changed it to your code `Could not determine JSON object type for type <>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, your initialization for `credentials` is correct. For the below error:

> Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

I checked your testing result via POSTMAN and found that you did not return `userId` to your client. The essential properties returned to your client would look like as follows:

```
{
   "authenticationToken":"***",
   "user":{
      "userId":"***"
   }
}
```

When using `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync`, the client SDK would internally invoke `LoginAsync()` method under [MobileServiceAuthentication.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Authentication/MobileServiceAuthentication.cs) as follows:

```
JToken authToken = JToken.Parse(response);

// Get the Mobile Services auth token and user data
this.Client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser((string)authToken["user"]["userId"]);

this.Client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = (string)authToken[LoginAsyncAuthenticationTokenKey];
```

You would find that it would try to extract the `userId` property under `user` to construct the `MobileServiceUser` instance and assign to `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser`.

Comment: Oh Bruce, you are legend. For some reason I thought it was just 'user' and not the value 'userId'. I should have checked the MobileServiceAuthentication.cs file , I will test this out and post results. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: It works, just a side question, is it ok to keep using InvokeApi instead? I mean what's the drawback

Comment: You could also use `InvokeApi`, at this point, you need to manually initialize / update your `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser` with the relevant `userId` and `authenticationToken`. Since `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` has handled it automatically for you, I would prefer to use `LoginAsync` for logging.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. I still have to set `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser` if I want to `reuse` same `authToken` the next time `MobileServiceClient` is initialised - I believe this is the correct approach to save authToken in `SharedPrefrences` for reusability as my tokenTimespam is 30 days?

Comment: You are right. Here is a complete tutorial about caching token in your mobile client side, details you could follow [Tokens in Real Apps](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#caching-tokens) about caching / refreshing the token. You could also specify `null` for the `lifetime` parameter when using `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken` for generating the JWT authenticationToken, then your client would get a never-expiring token.